# Convert row to character in R using all columns

Tags: r

I want to convert each row into a character consisting of the values in each column.

```
head(sequence_mat, 5)
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
 [1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [2,]    0    1    0    0    0    0
 [3,]    0    0    1    0    0    0
 [4,]    0    0    0    1    0    0
 [5,]    0    0    0    0    1    0
```

For example, `sequence_mat[1,] =  0    0    0    0    0    0` and I want it to become  `"0-0-0-0-0-0"`.

I tried `as.character(sequence_mat[1,])` but the output is not what I want, i.e. `[1] "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0"`

Comment: Try `apply(sequence_mat, 1, paste, collapse = "-")`

Comment: seems to work. Make a formal response so I can accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with

```
apply(sequence_mat, 1, paste, collapse = "-")
```

This runs through the array (matrix or dataframe) row-wise, pasting the elements together, with `-` separating them.